# Uploading images on google images JSON android

Tags: android, json, jsoup

I was wondering if it's possible to upload an image on the "[search by image](https://images.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl)" page using JSON or JSOUP in Android without using any Google API. Thanks in advance

Comment: i just want to bring up the file chooser whenever i click on the button and that should let me choose a picture from gallery and upload it to **google reverse image search page** (https://images.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 1):

```
Yes it is possible to convert an image in Base64 string and send to server using Json or any other way.
e.g.

Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.facebook);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, stream);                     byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: hello there i just want to bring up the file chooser whenever i click on the button and that should let me choose a picture from gallery and upload it to google reverse search page. thanks

Comment: here is the page i want to image to be uploaded on https://images.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl

Comment: Yes yo take a file from file chooser and convert it into BufferedImage or Bitmap and convert it into string and upload any where because the String we create from image is Base^4 string and you directly display it.

Comment: i have no idea how to do all that, i am new to android, i would be glad if you could give me a complete answer which works for my exact requirement thanks